# Export a custom framework from Xcode 6 for distribution

Tags: xcode, frameworks, xcode6

I was so excited when Apple said that in Xcode 6 developers can create custom frameworks. But, one question, how can I export the framework for a distribution or to embed it in another project? Could I export the .framework product resource?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the binary in the target app.

Go into project settings, select the general tab of the target.  Add the framework in the "Embedded Binaries" section.

Answer (score -2):

> how can I export the framework for a distribution or to embed it in another project?

Creating a framework is just a matter of adding a framework target to your project, or creating a new project with a framework target. When you build, you get a .framework file that you can add to any apps you like.

Comment: Yes, I thought that is the way. But, when I tried it, no way. There is errors on dylib. I built the framework, dragged the .framework into another project, built and nothing, error.

Comment: Yep i am getting same dylib error, any suggestion ?

Answer (score -3):

Hope it helpful for you [BPFrameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/BPFrameworks.pdf)

Comment: This is why we don't post links with no other context. They can break.